# Why presenting controller's view.transform gets reset on dismissal?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uikit, transition

I just started custom UIViewController transitions using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.
Everything went fine, but when I dismiss a view, the topography of the presenting view beneath (green) gets reset.

You can see it with *Cover*, and *Push* transitions.
**[| Click for GIF |](http://eppz.eu/blog/wp-content/uploads/ViewControllerTransition.gif)**

[image]

If you listen *Cover* transition carefully, you can see my problem. As soon as I click for dismiss, the **presenting (green) view get's transformed back to fullscreen**, while it's `alpha` works as I expect (!). Stays on `0.5` and animate toward `1.0` as it should be. This is not the case with `transform` of `frame`properties.

Same goes for *Push* transition, the presenting controller's view gets reset right after click. The modal view just fine.

---

I've put **[the project to GitHub](https://github.com/eppz/labs-transitions)**, actually made some helper class to cut down boilerplate, but you'll get the point. See **[`EPPZPartialCover`](https://github.com/eppz/labs-transitions/blob/master/Transitions/EPPZPartialCover.m)** for a transition implementation.

Comment: Geri, I looked at your project on github, but, on the Cover transition, there still appears to be a slight flicker on the presenting view when the dismiss transition starts. Did you ever manage to fix this? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: Yap. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of animation option `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`.
Removed that animation option, and transition works as expected.